# Cannot emit an error from a Cloud Function to Stackdriver Error Reporting

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried this way (Manually reporting errors), but this is not working in firebase cloud functions.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors?hl=en

I tried to call this function in local environment and it worked.
I tried to call this function in firebase cloud functions and it didn't work.

This is the function I deployed.

```
exports.hello = https.onRequest((_, response) => {
  const error = new Error('ERROR!!!!')
  return reportError(error)
    .then(result => {
      response.json(result); // {}
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err); // No error
    });
})

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors?hl=en#sending_to_stackdriver
function reportError(err, context = {}) {
  // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that will receive the log
  // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but must contain "err"
  // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error Reporting.
  const logName = 'errors';
  const log = logging.log(logName);

  // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
  const metadata = {
    resource: {
      type: 'cloud_function',
      labels: {function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME},
    },
  };

  // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
  const errorEvent = {
    message: err.stack,
    serviceContext: {
      service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
      resourceType: 'cloud_function',
    },
    context: context,
  };

  // Write the error log entry
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
      if (error) {
       return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

`function reportError` is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors?hl=en#sending_to_stackdriver

This is package.json I used.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-tools": "6.8.0"
  }
}
```

reportError function should emit a report to Stackdriver Error Reporting.

Comment: I'm not expert in Firebase nor NodeJS, but it looks like your function `hello` **must** return an error to be reported to Stackdriver Error Reporting (see this example : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors#functions-errors-log-nodejs). Could you try to replace `response.end('')` by `return reportError(error);` and check if you see the error in Stackdriver?

Comment: @norbjd thank you, I tried this: `return reportError(error).then(result => response.json(result))` and I can get result (`{}`) but I cannot see any logs in Error Reporting yet.

Comment: From the example in the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors#sending_to_stackdriver, see `createStripeCharge` function), `return reportError(error)` is the **last** statement and there is no `response.json(...)` call. It looks like that by doing `.then(result => response.json(result))`, you are in the `// These will NOT be reported to Stackdriver Error Reporting` case of this example : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors#functions-errors-log-nodejs. Can you just try `return reportError(error)` (no `then` after)?

Comment: @norbjd I tried `return reportError(error)` (no then after) but I cannot see Error reporting.